# Vue Bootstrap Calendar in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

Does anyone know how to integrate [Vue Bootstrap Calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-calendar) in Laravel 5.4 ?

After installing it, i'm trying this on assets/js/app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('Calendar', require('vue-bootstrap-calendar'));
```

but when I run `num run dev`, I get this error:

> Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "latest" relative to
>   directory "../node_modules/vue-bootstrap-calendar"

I also tried with:

require( 'vue-i18n' );

```
require( 'vue-i18n' );    
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages
});
Vue.component('Calendar', require('vue-bootstrap-calendar'));
```

But still the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit outdated, but just in case... It needs babel-preset-latest

> npm install --save-dev babel-preset-latest

Answer (score 0):

If your project don't run any frontend engineering(webpack, babel...), you can use the Vue Calendar compile file as:
https://github.com/EazyServer/Vue-Bootstrap-Calendar/blob/master/dist/vbc-browser.js

example:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('Calendar', require('vue-bootstrap-calendar/dist/vbc-browser'));
```

But I suggest you add the frontend engineering to your project.